# GCP - Google Cloud Platform - Creating Instance from Snapshot Issue

Tags: image, google-cloud-platform, ssh, instance, snapshot

I am having an issue that is causing me to pull my hair out. I have an vm instance running in GCP and all I basically want to do is move it from the zone USA to EUROPE as it connects to a database in EUROPE remotely.

I have created a snapshot and then spun up a new instance in EUROPE via said snapshot but I can't for the life of me SSH onto it or even ping it! It gives me an intermitant ping every so often which is really strange and even using gcloud to ssh onto it using the

```
gcloud compute config-ssh
```

doesn't work. It just times out. There is no firewall on the instance itself and all the relevant ports are open on the GCP firewall. Am I missing something? Is there a setting on the instance itself that is stopping me from replicating it?

Comment: Connect via the serial port and review the boot logs for problems.

Comment: Also check the serial port logs to see if the instance is running into any issue that is preventing your to login.